# R - create a string of quoted numbers

Tags: sql, r, string, oracle

I have a vector of numbers `a <- 1:5` and I want to end up with a string like:

```
b <- " '1', '2', '3', '4', '5' "
```

(a string of strings)

I cant figure out how to do this succinctly in R.

I need to pass this as part of an SQL statement; the DB (Oracle) stores these "numbers" as characters hence this conversion.

Comment: What's your dbms?

Comment: @D-Shih. Edited post: Oracle

Comment: Your `1` and `5` is in two columns in Oracle?

Comment: I'm not an R expert, but I think you should add an R tag if you're looking for help figuring out how to do this in R ;-)

Comment: It's poor design that the database has a character column to store numeric detail. Even so, Oracle will happen the datatype conversion implicitly. Maybe you're trying to solve a problem that doesn't really exist. What have you tried so far? What happened?

Comment: @APC. Thanks! It is poor design!. However, If i create a sql statement in oracle sql developer, i can indeed use numeric values, but if i pass the same statement from R via RODBC connect, i do not get the same result returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`paste0()` with `collapse = ", "` is what you want:

```
a <- 1:5
b <- paste0("'", a, "'", collapse = ", ")
b

# [1] "'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'"
```

Answer (score 0):

> paste("'", 1:5, "'", collapse = ", ", sep = "")
>   [1] "'1', '2', '3', '4', '5'"